# how to use datatable in jsp ? after retriving data in table form from database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, datatables

I have created a jsp file which fetchs data from the database in table form now i have to use datatable so please someone suggest how to do it . in output it shows table which contains data in form  of row and column but my sir asked to use datatable in it . so it will be a great help if someone can answer

CODE -

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%
String id = request.getParameter("userId");
String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "xyz";
String userId = "1234";
String password = "1234";

try {
Class.forName(driverName);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<h2 align="center">Fetch Data From Database in Jsp</h2>
<table  id="details" class="display" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
    <thead>
<tr>
<th><b>First Name</b></th>
<th><b>Last Name</b></th>
<th><b>Address</b></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<%
try{ 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
statement=connection.createStatement();
String sql ="SELECT * FROM details";

resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while(resultSet.next()){
%>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("firstname")%></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("lastname") %></td>
<td><%=resultSet.getString("Address") %></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<% 
}
connection.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
%>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please someone help .... it is a jsp file ...i have to implment databale in it

Comment: you just need to add required cdn and then  initialize datatable under `$(document).ready..`